# Cordova InAppBrowser plugin is not installed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

When I list plugins (`cordova plugin list`), it is listed there but when I run my code on an android device I get this message in the console (from chrome remote debugger):
`Native: InAppBrowser is not installed or you are running on a browser. Falling back to window.open, all instance methods will NOT work.`

I have the latest version of ionic-cli.

I've included a sample project here: https://github.com/golear91/ionic2-broken-inappbrowser

I basically:

- used the cli to "start" a tabs project
- added a single provider (using generator)
- added provider to one of my tabs
- `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`
- import & attempt to use `InAppBrowser`

I tried removing and reinstalling using the plugin to no avail.

Any ideas for what is wrong?

Comment: Well, keep in mind that isn't an error. It just a warning, telling that it probably may not work in browser. Just it.

Comment: I know that it doesn't work in a browser, I am however testing it on an android device so it should not be spitting this message out. (The instance methods mentioned in fact do not work and I need them which is why I asked the question). I've gotten it to work before without spitting the error out but I don't know what I am doing wrong this time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usage of ionic-native plugins must wait on the device being "ready"

For Ionic2 with Angular this can be achieved by importing Platform (with every thing else) to whichever component/service you plan on using the ionic-native plugin from.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { InAppBrowser } from 'ionic-native';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
```

and then waiting on the platform being ready:

```
@Injectable()
export class Service() {
   constructor(public platform: Platform) {
     this.init()
   }
   init() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
       let browser = new InAppBrowser('https://ionic.io', '_system');
       browser.on("loadstop").subscribe(()=> console.log("loadstop"));
     });
   }
}
```

Comment: but where to add this code? improve your answer on how to do this

Comment: @AlokRajasukumaran you must import the platform to whatever component/service you want to use the ionic-native plugin from (added to the answer).

Answer (score 1):

To add in plugins/android.json and plugins/ios.json

```
"cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {}
```

This worked for me.

I hope to help you.

Regards.